# Is the networkx.MultiDiGraph.edges method order-preserving?

Tags: python, networkx

MyNetwork is an instance of networkx.MultiDiGraph. I'm wondering if multiple runs of the following code is guaranteed to result exactly the same list containing all edges (along with edge attributes) in MyNetwork:

```
AllEdges = [(from_node,to_node,edge_key,edge_attributes) for (from_node,to_node,edge_key,edge_attributes) in MyNetwork.edges(keys=True,data=True)]
```

Thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of edges returned from the MultiDiGraph.edges() method is not guaranteed to be in any order or the same when called repeatedly.  You'll have to do more processing (e.g. a sort) or maintain a separate list or symbol table of edges if you need a particular ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Does this generalize to DiGraph and Graph as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the same for all of the graph classes.  There is no implied or guaranteed ordering of the nodes or edges.