# How to stop Networkx from changing the order of edges when adding them from a list?

Tags: python, networkx

Adding edges from a list to a graph in NetworkX (python) changes the order of the edges, which causes problems for me when drawing the Graph.
As example:

```
import networkx as nx

airports = ['A','B','C']
edgelst  = [['C','B'],['A','B'],['A','C']]

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(airports)
G.add_edges_from(edgelst)
```

This is the result if I check for the existing edges in the network:

```
>>> G.edges()
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B')]
```

NetworkX has sorted the edges alphabetically, but I just want them to be in the same order as edgelst. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I think that you question can be related to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258894/is-the-networkx-multidigraph-edges-method-order-preserving

Comment: It is indeed related to that question, thank you. I see that it is impossible to do what I want, so I am trying to find a way to code around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is a bit messy because the NetworkX `Graph` class doesn't retain the order of nodes in an edge. However, this can be circumvented by sorting each edge to guarantee node order. `G.edges()` can also be sorted by a custom key that retrieves the index that each edge appears in the edge list.

```
import networkx as nx

edgelist  = [['C','B'],['A','B'],['A','C']]
```

First, sort the nodes in each edge and create a dictionary that maps each edge to its index in the edge list:

```
edgelist = [sorted(edge) for edge in edgelist]
mapping = {tuple(edge): index for (edge, index) in zip(edgelist, range(len(edgelist)))}
```

Then sort the order of the graph's edges according to the index edges in the edge list:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edgelist)
sorted(G.edges(), key=lambda edge: mapping[tuple(sorted(list(edge)))])
```

Comment: I believe this answer is out of date - see https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/ordered.html

Comment: @Joel, no it is not. Replace `nx.Graph()` with `nx.ordered.Graph()` in the original post, and `G.edges()` will give you `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]`.

Comment: Yes - I see that now.  The documentation says "The order of node reporting agrees with node adding, but for edges, the order is not necessarily the order that the edges were added."

Comment: I have just tried this on a larger graph (10000 nodes with random coordinates in [0, 1] + the knn graph with 10 neighbors) and the order is not adjusted with this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a traversal algorithm you can get the edges in the order they were visited in the path

```

> > > paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=0, target=3)
> > >       for path in map(nx.utils.pairwise, paths):
> > >       ...     print(list(path))
> > >       [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
> > >       [(0, 1), (1, 3)]
> > >       [(0, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3)]
> > >       [(0, 2), (2, 3)]
> > >       [(0, 3)]
> > >       ```