# How to prevent the networkx_edge_labels shuffling during assignment for a visualization

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph, networkx

I have the code. When i draw the graph, the labels are shuffling and not showing correctly. I have consulted the reference guide (https://networkx.org/documentation) and related post (i.e. [How to stop Networkx from changing the order of edges when adding them from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875280/how-to-stop-networkx-from-changing-the-order-of-edges-when-adding-them-from-a-li)) but i cant help it.

The data which i am using is [image: Data Picture]].

When i print the values of

```
dict(zip(G.edges, df['value'].tolist()))
```

It gives me the wrong assignment of the labels. For example, in Row No. 2, ('aquatic communities', 'biocoenosis') should be "Borader".

It is shown below;

```
{('plankton', 'aquatic communities'): 'broader',
 ('plankton', 'zooplankton'): 'broader',
 ('plankton', 'phytoplankton'): 'narrower',
 ('plankton', 'cryoplankton'): 'narrower',
 ('plankton', 'nannoplankton'): 'narrower',
 ('plankton', 'picoplankton'): 'narrower',
 ('plankton', 'plankton surveys'): 'narrower',
 ('aquatic communities', 'biocoenosis'): 'related'}
```

Code for Plotting;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Build a dataframe with your connections
# df = results_df_4a[results_df_4a["value"] == 'broader']
  df = results_df_4a
# And I need to transform my categorical column in a numerical value typeA->1, typeB->2...
df['value']=pd.Categorical(df['value'])
df['value'].cat.codes
 
# Build your graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph(directed=True) )
 
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=3)

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=120)

# Custom the nodes:
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, font_size = 10, with_labels=True, arrows=True, node_color= 'skyblue', node_size= 700, width= 3.5, arrowstyle= '-|>', arrowsize= 12, edge_color=df['value'].cat.codes)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos = pos, edge_labels=dict(zip(G.edges, df['value'].tolist())))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about directly creating the graph with the `edge_label` information you want to use:

```
# Build your graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
      df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph(directed=True),
     edge_attr='value'    
)
```

Based on that you could follow easily the "usual procedure" to add edge labels from edge attributes, see [Labeling edges in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094949/labeling-edges-in-networkx).

### Edit 1

A full minimal working example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

g = nx.DiGraph()

g.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 3)])

pos = nx.spring_layout(g)

nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True)

# in above case you need to use 'value' instead of 'weight' here
edge_labels = dict([((n1, n2), d['weight'])
                    for n1, n2, d in g.edges(data=True)])

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels,)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gives the same result. There is a mismatch in the colors assignments. The networkX takes only the direct relation with Plankton and then the 2nd relations originating from Plankton.

Comment: So with wrong assignment, you mean the return of `G.edges(data=True)`? Or do you mean your statement `dict(zip(G.edges, df['value'].tolist()))`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I mean to say that, when it computes G.edges, it ignores the relation that is shown in Figure above i.e. (aquatic communities and aquatic communities -> broader ) and put it to the last order. When i use dict(zip(G.edges, df['value'].tolist())) statement, as the G.edges are reordered by the library, it wrongly assigns the values to the edges.

Comment: You should replace this `dict(zip(....))` statement, please check my extended answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I wish you a good day !