# The unambiguity of choosing the shortest path in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I have a graph:

[image]

Why after using functions of the shortest path:

```
nx.shortest_path(g, 0, 6)
```

Why is the output path is `[0, 3, 6]`? Why not `[0, 2, 6]`? Is the selection of the path `[0, 3, 6]` for the algorithm `shortest_path()` always unambiguous in the above case?

Comment: What do you mean by "unambigious"? That happens to be the path first found in the search order... if you connect the nodes in different orders or the underlying implementation of the storage of the edges changes, then it's possible the route via node `2` is tried first...

Comment: It probably depends on the order in which you specify the edges. So the same graph can have different shortest paths. You always obtain *one* of the shortest paths.

Comment: If you look a the networkx code you should be able to see how it stores its edges... whether it implies any ordering to an adjacency list or uses something else will provide more details...

Comment: unambiguous, that is, it was actually the shortest path, and not only found as the first of all the shortest paths.

Comment: Does it mean that if I keep the original order of creating edges, then choosing the shortest path will be the same?

Comment: If networkx traverses edges in order they were added... then yes... otherwise - the ordering may be a side effect of how they're stored and it just so happens that in this case - the first search path happened to traverse the edge to node 3 instead of node 2...

Comment: Right.. according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258894/is-the-networkx-multidigraph-edges-method-order-preserving there's no implicit ordering to the edge list (insertion order or value order) - so unless networkx has changed recently... then the answer is - you'll get a shortest_path and you'll get the same one for the same graph, but as soon as you modify edges, bets are off...

Comment: (although - there's been changes to `dict` in 3.6 which means they effectively retain some order and probably make it look like its ordered  - but again - that's a side effect of how the edges are stored and not a guarantee of networkx)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I will still read more about the topic.

Comment: In summary... it's whether networkx is storing your graph as `{0: [3, 2], 2: [6, 4], 3: [5, 6]}` and the edges are ordered because they're lists or whether it's `{0: {3, 2}, 2: {6, 4}, 3: {5, 6}}` where they're sets which are more efficient to checking the target but iteration order is pot-luck (although consistent unless they're mutated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jon-clements has the correct answer in the comments to the question.  If there is more then one shortest path the function `networkx.shortest_path()` will return one of them.  The specific path you get is dependent on how the data is stored in the `networkx` graph data structure (Python dictionary based) and not guaranteed to be deterministic.  You can get all of the shortest paths if you like and even sort them to provide a stable order - e.g.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph({0: [3, 2], 2: [6, 4], 3: [5, 6]})

In [3]: nx.shortest_path(G, 0, 6)
Out[3]: [0, 2, 6]

In [4]: list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, 0,6))
Out[4]: [[0, 3, 6], [0, 2, 6]]

In [5]: sorted(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, 0,6))
Out[5]: [[0, 2, 6], [0, 3, 6]]
```